# Elasticsearch cluster each nodes doesn't recognize other nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I'm working on setting up a 3-node Elasticsearch cluster, each node successfully runs but can't recognize other nodes.

Private IPs of each host is 10.213.72.1, 10.213.72.2, 10.213.72.3, respectively, so I put those in discovery.seed_hosts.

This is the config I used. All 3 nodes has the exact same config.

```
[user@host1 elasticsearch]$ cat config/elasticsearch.yml
cluster.name: my-es-cluster
node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
path.data: "/home/user/elasticsearch/data"
path.logs: "/home/user/elasticsearch/logs"
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
transport.port: 9300
discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.213.72.1", "10.213.72.2", "10.213.72.3"]
```

Each node itself runs, but I can't discover other nodes.

```
curl -X GET localhost:9200/_nodes | jq .
{
  "_nodes": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Where are the nodes deployed? Are they running on the same machine?

Comment: They are deployed on different machine. That's why there are 3 ips in discovery.seed_hosts.

Comment: But you said you're using private IPs, then the machines cannot communicate with each other using those. Have you tried to ping a machine from another?

Comment: I figured out why. The issue was that I didn't specify cluster.intial_master_nodes at the startup.